# How to use slice for update an object in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i tried to change the content of on object in array, but without success, i tried with setstate ecc..

```
deleteRecipient = () => { //works
  this.setState(prev => ({
    recipients: [
      ...prev.recipients.slice(0, this.state.recipientSelectedIndex),
      ...prev.recipients.slice(this.state.recipientSelectedIndex + 1)
    ],
    recipientsDialogVisible: !prev.recipientsDialogVisible
  }))
};
```

This code delete a specific index, how can use the same code for update?
this.state.recipientSelectedIndex is my index saved, for example 2

The array to update is the following:

```
newRecipient:{
  email: null,
  name: null,
  notificationType:{ //not this object
    SMS: false,
    email: false
  },//
  phone: null
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using slice, you can use map and update

```
updateRecipient = (newRecipient) => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      recipients: prev.recipients.map((item) => {
          if (item.email === newRecipient.email) {
              return {...item, ...newRecipient}
          }
          return item;
      })
    }))
  };
```

With slice the solution becomes a little bit difficult to read, but will work as

```
updateRecipient = (newRecipient) => { 
    const idx = this
    this.setState(prev => {
       return {
        recipients:  [...prev.recipients.slice(0, prev.recipientSelectedIndex), {...prev.recipients[prev.recipientSelectedIndex], ...newRecipient},
        ...prev.recipients.slice(prev.recipientSelectedIndex + 1)],
      }
    }))
  };
```

Comment: So,  onChange = {(e)=> this.updateRecipient(e.target.value)} for take value of input that i want to change

Comment: @mantegnous In the above code we expect the entire object, but you can pass the key value pair as well

Comment: My state is this.state.recipients: this.props.recipients.map(d => ({...d, notificationType: d.notificationType || {SMS: true, email: true}})),

my onchange for input email this.updateRecipient('email')} ?